# Oracle sql: not a valid month

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, oracle, date

This is what I do I'm adding a date to the paramater and I want to get all records where the first day of that month is between dtwo dates. But when I do this I get an error:"not a valid month". This is the problem to_date(to_char(trunc(to_date(s.startdatum),'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY')). I want to have to first day of the month of that date

```
Dim stagiairs As DataTable = udao.getToekomstigeEnHuidigeStagiairs(New Date(2014, 05, 01))

       Public Function getToekomstigeEnHuidigeStagiairs(udate As Date) As DataTable
        Dim paramlist As New List(Of OracleParameter)
        Dim maand As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter()
        maand.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
        maand.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date
        maand.ParameterName = "datum"
        maand.Value = udate
        paramlist.Add(maand)

        strSQL = "SELECT s.stageid, (p.naam || ' ' || p.voornaam) as naam,(beg.naam || ' ' || beg.voornaam) as begeleider,s.STARTDATUM, s.einddatum FROM TAB_STGSP_GEBRUIKER p join TAB_STGSP_STAGE s on (p.id = s.stagiairid) join TAB_STGSP_Gebruiker beg on (beg.id = s.begeleiderid) where p.goedgekeurd = 1 and **to_char(to_date(:datum,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM-DD-YYYY')** between to_date(to_char(trunc(s.startdatum,'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY')) and s.EINDDATUM"
        Return util.selecteer(strSQL, paramlist)
    End Function
```

What I'm trying to do with this query is check if the first day of the month of the date in the paramater is between the first day of the month of the startingdate and the ending date

Comment: needs a language tag (Visual Basic?)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here:

```
to_date(to_char(trunc(s.startdatum,'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

If s.startdatum is a date column and you want to use only the month value you can just use:

```
trunc(s.startdatum, 'MM')
```

This will give you the first of the month.

Edit:
What goes wrong is the following:

```
**to_char()** between to_date(
```

You are comparing character string s to dates. Make sure the first statement results in a date value in order to compare it to the date values.

```
to_date(:datum,'DD/MM/YYYY') between to_date...
```

Comment: to_date(to_char(trunc(s.startdatum,'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY')) I use this to get the first day of the month
to_char(to_date(:datum,'DD/MM/YYYY') and this to change the MM/DD/YYYY date to a DD/MM/YYYY date

Comment: You're right this is wrong to_date(to_char(trunc(s.startdatum,'MM'),'DD-MM-YYYY')) I want the first day of the month of the s.startdatum